# How can I take a parameter link in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have in twig template an anchor tag :

```
 <a href="{{ path('park_resort_calculator', {'price': ad.price }) }}"><button id="redirect_calculator">Calculator</button></a>
```

How can I take the value of ad.price in the template `park_resort_calculator` ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the query string parameters in a template using

```
 {{ app.request.get('price')  }}
```

Some reference of the app shortcut [here in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#app)
Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly, in your controller uou need something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/calculate/{price}", name="park_resort_calculator")
 */
public function calculateAction($price)
{
    echo $price;
    // ...
}
```

Oh... you shouldn't nest a `<button>` inside an `<a>` tag.... it may cause issues.